# static/global variable not permitted in C++

Tags: c++, cpplint

I have defined a global variable in my C++ class as follows :

```
std::string VAR = "HELLO_WORLD";
```

But cpplint is telling me :

> Static/global string variables are not permitted.  [runtime/string]
>   [4]

Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation at all? https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## For the avoidance of doubt the language itself permits this.

Essentially though the static analyser you are using forbids this because `std::string` contains a *constructor* so the statement actually "does something".

Therefore it needs to be inside a function, not at global scope.

On the other hand,

```
const char* VAR = "HELLO_WORLD";
```

is emitted, since that's no more than an assignment of a read-only `const char[]` literal to an appropriate pointer.

Comment: Types with constructors can be global variables. They'll be dynamically initialized and all those good stuff. `std::string` can't be a `constexpr` variable, but the OP doesn't indicate this is the case.

Comment: _"needs to be"_ in what sense? Presumably just an arbitrary judgment made by `cpplint`, not the language. Yes, objects at namespace scope are prone to the static initialisation order fiasco and probably inadvisable for other reasons too, but they're perfectly well-defined when used correctly.

Comment: What?! Instantiating classes having non-trivial ctors at namespace/global scope is perfectly legal! Maybe Cpplint just says it's against google coding conventions.

Comment: Just link and quote https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables and be done with it, as the OP could have read that. :P

Comment: On re-reading this answer was implying the *language* didn't allow it. I hope I make that clear now.